# Build Cython Extension with pypy3-v5.10.1 want to use Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cython, setup.py, pypy, appveyor

Pypy3

Python 3.5.3 (3f6eaa010fce, Jan 11 2018, 04:46:12)
[PyPy 5.10.1 with MSC v.1500 32 bit]

Cython 0.28.1

https://ci.appveyor.com/project/nooperpudd/ctpwrapper/build/1.0.396/job/xx7ecwgy5bqvu0up#L18

in appveryor.yml file I already add

```
image:
  - Visual Studio 2015
```

But the C++ compile still use  Visual Studio 9.0 to compile C++ extension.

Instead I want to use  Visual Studio 14.0 (2015) to build the extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Starting about a month ago we use Visual Studio 14 to build PyPy3 on win32 on the nightly builds. You can download a nightly build from [here](http://buildbot.pypy.org/nightly/py3.5/). I am not sure how to get appveyor to download and use that version, I think [PyGame](https://github.com/pygame/pygame) has some scripts that work to download, compile pygame, and test using appveyor and nightly builds

Comment: I tried, They don't use Visual Studio 14 to build pypy3 with cython, instead of the visual c++ for python 9.0

Comment: What did you try? On line 7 of your appveyor log you download `https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/pypy3-v5.10.1-win32.zip`. I am suggesting you download http://buildbot.pypy.org/nightly/py3.5/pypy-c-jit-latest-win32.zip instead. Since it is built with VS 2015, it will try to use that version of VS to build your extensions

Comment: pypy-5.10.1 Python 3.5.3 (3f6eaa010fce, Jan 11 2018, 04:46:12)
[PyPy 5.10.1 with MSC v.1500 32 bit ,

Comment: pypy-6.10.1 Python 3.5.3 (4db4624409b4, Apr 13 2018, 01:02:02)
[PyPy 6.1.0-alpha0 with MSC v.1910 32 bit]